# Как с помощью web audio api воспроизводить буферы, которые приходят по ws?

Tags: node.js, websocket, потоки-данных, web-audio

У меня backend на nodejs. С помощью пакета [mic](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mic) захватываю звук с микрофона (звук захватывается с микрофона на сервере). Далее с помощью пакета [wav](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wav) преобразую поток в формат wav и отправляю на фронт с помощью websocket

Пример кода на бэкэнде nodejs:

```
micInstance = mic({
            rate: '16000',
            channels: '1',
            debug: true,
            exitOnSilence: 6
        });
micInputStream = micInstance.getAudioStream();
micInstance.start();
var writer = new wav.Writer({
    "channels": 1,
    "sampleRate": 16000,
    "bitDepth": 16
});
writer.pipe(micInputStream).on('data', function (data) {
    var response = JSON.stringify({'id': 'getAudio', 'result': 'ok', 'detail': data});
    conn.send(response);
    console.log("Recieved Input Stream: " + data.length);
});
```

На фронте принимаю эти данные и пытаюсь их воспроизвести с помощью web audio api:

```
var bufferLength = data.detail.data.length;
    var arrayBuffer = this.audio_context.createBuffer(1, bufferLength, 16000);
    for (var i = 0; i < bufferLength; i++) {
        arrayBuffer[i] = data.detail.data[i];
    }
    var destination = this.audio_context.destination;
    this.audio_source = this.audio_context.createBufferSource();
    this.audio_source.buffer = arrayBuffer;
    this.audio_source.connect(destination);
    this.audio_source.start(0);
```

Уже перепробовал кучу вариантов как воспроизводить полученные буферы: делал и по клику на кнопку, и пытался встроить в тег audio итд. Но так и не выходит воспроизвести. Тот вариант кода, который я написал выше, даже ошибок никаких не выводит, то есть просто тишина. Не могу понять в чем проблема. Может кто подсказать, что я делаю не правильно и как нужно делать?

Answer (score 4):

Вы отправляете WAV файл (в котором присутствуют заголовки) в качестве аудио буффера (где должны быть чистые данные). Я попробовал без пакета `wav` и у меня кое-как получилось услышать себя из микрофона. Тестировал на Windows. Не уверен, имеет ли это значение, но пакет `mic` использует внешнюю утилиту `sox` на Windows/Mac и `arecord` на Linux.

**Сервер:**

```
var micInstance = mic({
    rate: 16000,
    channels: 1,
    bitwidth: 16,
    debug: true
});

var micInputStream = micInstance.getAudioStream();
micInstance.start();

micInputStream.on('data', (chunk) => {
    // отправляем байты напрямую
    // я здесь использовал пакет websocket
    connection.sendBytes(chunk);
});
```

**Клиент:**

```
var context = new AudioContext();
var ws = new WebSocket('...', '...');
ws.onmessage = async function (msg) {
    const channels = 1;
    const rate = 16000;
    const bits = 16;
    var buffer = context.createBuffer(channels, msg.data.size / bits * 8 / channels, rate);
    // в вашем примере вы пишете напрямую в аудио буффер, что неправильно
    // нужно получить Float32Array и писать в него
    var channel = buffer.getChannelData(0);
    // превращаем Blob (msg.data) в ArrayBuffer
    var arrayBuffer = await new Response(msg.data).arrayBuffer();
    // если на сервере будет стоять bitwidth=8, тогда придется использовать Int8Array, и т.д.
    var array = new Int16Array(arrayBuffer, 0, arrayBuffer.byteLength / bits * 8);
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        // в массиве channel должны быть значения в пределах -1..1
        // строчка ниже превращает Int16 в вещественное число из интервала -1..1
        channel[i] = array[i] / 128 / 256;
    }

    var source = context.createBufferSource();
    source.buffer = buffer;
    source.connect(context.destination);
    // я не определил, откуда берется эта двойка
    // возможно из-за того, что в context.destination 2 канала
    // а в нашем аудиобуффере всего один
    source.playbackRate.value = 2;
    source.start();
};
```